# Возможно ли создать БД из таблиц Excel на VBA?

Tags: sql, база-данных, excel, vba

Собственно сам вопрос из заголовка. Дали такое задание в университете и время самим разобраться. Гуглил, читал, разные есть подходы, но я не пойму фундамента сего действия. Могу ли я из таблиц, набранных на листах Excel создать БД. Где создать отношения (без VBA) уже нашел. Но все это бестолку, если я не понимаю главного. Могу ли я использовать эти таблицы с их связями для создания SQL запросов непосредственно внутри макросов на VBA? Прошу прощения за дилетантское описание, потому что первый раз с таким сталкиваюсь и даже представления не имею о структуре. Насколько реально создать базу из таблиц («умных»), построенных между ними отношениях и выполнение SQL запросов на основе только данных Excel, не подключая никаких внешних файлов, типа файла готовой Access БД, сервера и т.д.?
Если да, подскажите пожалуйста, где почитать как это реализовать, не могу сориентироваться. Благодарю.

Comment: Вопрос очень размытый. Из любых структурированных таблиц можно оздать базу данных

Comment: @vikttur я Вас понимаю. Попытаюсь немного конкретизировать. В процессе поиска информации по созданию БД в среде Excel с использованием VBA, в силу своей некомпетентности, столкнулся с ощущением, что я не могу выполнять запросы на языке SQL имея «на руках» только таблицы на листе Excel с выстроенными отношениями между ними. Что мне обязательно нужно обращаться к какому-то внешнему ядру БД, чаще всего в статьях идет речь о связи с Access. В моем  случае, я пытаюсь узнать, могу ли выполнять эти запросы не обращаясь к каким-то внешним файлам, а исключительно на таблицах из листов Excel (на VBA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подключение к книги в качестве источника данных - вполне рядовая операция на определенном классе задач автоматизации офисной работы. Для этого используются интерфейсы передачи данных (например ADO - ActiveX Data Objects).

Подробнее об ADO и его использовании при подключении к книге Excell в качестве источника данных с примерами можно почитать [здесь](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/278973/excelado-demonstrates-how-to-use-ado-to-read-and-write-data-in-excel-w)